# document.domain with a 2-letter domain name bugs in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, dns

We have a domain name with two letters in it. This is a problem with IE, for all versions.

The problem is that when we set `document.domain="xx.yy"` we get an "invalid argument" exception.

Does anyone have a solution or an idea on how to work around this bug?

Regards,
Tobias

Comment: what if u try document.domain = "xx.yy";

Comment: I just didn't add that to the example. I'll change it to clarify. The problem is well-known that IE doesn't handle two-letter domains very well. Just wants to know how to work around this.

Comment: Are you Tobias at the bottom of [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/19/private-domain-names-and-public-suffixes-in-internet-explorer.aspx) ;) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are limitations on what domains can be used as a shared parent domain for cross-document scripting and cookie sharing.

This is deliberate: otherwise, `example.co.uk` and `other-example.co.uk` could act as part of the same site `co.uk`. Browsers don't want to allow this, for privacy and security reasons.

The problem is that the DNS system doesn't have an official way to state that `co.uk` is a registry-allocated domain under which separate organisations live, but `bit.ly` is a single organisation. This is even harder in some places, like `.jp` which has both direct organisation subdomains and registry-allocated subdomains like `co.jp`.

So browsers have internal rules of what domains should be taken as ‘public’ and shouldn't be allowed to share scripting/credentials context, and these rules have to be updated when there are new TLDs and SLDs. Older browsers may not recognise newer domains.

Some browsers take their information from the [Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/), though not IE. IE would appear to be using the heuristic that, for a TLD it doesn't know about and have a special-case for, a 2-letter subdomain `xx.yy` is likely to be a public domain (like `co.uk`, `or.jp` or whatever) and shouldn't be allowed to act as a shared parent domain. This is a reasonable guess, IMO: better to ‘fail safe’.

I don't think you're going to be able to circumvent it. What are you trying to do, might there be another way around? Can you put all the cross-subdomain scripting stuff in a sub-subdomain?

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/19/private-domain-names-and-public-suffixes-in-internet-explorer.aspx

Comment: @Eric: Hey, I just wrote there. Looking for the answer to the same question as posted here.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. Sort of the same information that Eric Law posted. It's very good info.

We are trying to do use a sub-subdomain to fix it, but so far have been unable to do so.

Do you know this? Will a frame on domain www.xx.tt be able to communicate with yyy.www.xx.tt?

Comment: Yes, if both set their domains to `www.xx.tt` you should be fine.

Comment: Very good to know! Must try it out again then and see if we can't make it work. On another node we just found this thing, http://easyxdm.net/ which might also help us fixing this.